# Tesseract - Android

Tags: android, config, tesseract

I've been doing some searching on the internet how to achive the OCRed picture and some says to use "tessedit_write_images T" but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried to use .setVariable("tessedit_write_images", "T"); but nothing happened. Is there anything more e.g. call a method to push it to an output file or it should work like this?

Regards, Mike